# Async methods in Xamarin.iOS throws System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

The next line of code

```
var response = await _restService.GetAsync<IdentificationResponseDto>(identificationUri, new CancellationToken());
```

throws:

> System.ExecutionEngineException has been thrown
>   Attemting to JIT compile method .... While running with --aot-only.

where my rest service GetAsync method is:

```
 public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return ProcessResult<T>(responseString);
    }

private T ProcessResult<T>(string responseString) where T : new()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseString))
        {
            return _converter.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
        }

        return default(T);
    }

public T DeserializeObject<T>(string inputText)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(inputText, Settings);
    }
```

when running on emulator everything works fine, but when trying to debug on a device (ipad2) i get the error. tried also to set the GetAsync method to allow only class type
using "where T: class, new()" with no help.

JsonConvert is taken from Json.Net library.

Important to mention that when i initializee my restService using

```
RestService _restService = new RestService(...)
```

everything works fine and no error, but when i initialize it using

```
IRestService _restService = new RestService(...)
```

where IRestService  is an interface, The error occurs.

any help?

Comment: I found that this is a bug with xamarin.ios,
for full description of the bug please see:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12746